# How to write a dynamic route in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm trying to write a generic route that will allow me to refer to it by the controller's action.

I'm using the following line:

```
  match ':action' => 'pages#:action', :as => 'action'
```

let's say an action named `foobar' in the pages controller. I'd like to be able to write

```
link_to 'Click Me', pages_foobar_path
```

in a view. The problem is that I get the error `Invalid route name: ':action'` when I try to write that route.

Mind you, the line

```
match ':action' => 'pages#:action'
```

without the `:as` parameter works perfectly, but then I have to manually write the path, as such:

```
link_to 'Click Me', '/pages/foobar'
```

any way around that?

Answer (score 5):

**If *dynamic* means "recognize my actions when Rails starts up and generate routes dynamically":**

It's not something that I would do, but it does what *you* want it to do without any redirection nor method_missing runtime overhead.

In `config/routes.rb`

```
controller_filenames = Dir.new("#{Rails.root}/app/controllers").entries
controller_filenames.each do |filename|
  # you could restrict to only the pages_controller.rb on the next line,
  # and in that case, you could simplify even more (see next example)...
  if filename =~ /_controller\.rb$/
    controller_name = filename.sub(/.rb$/, "")
    controller_route_name = controller_name.sub(/_controller$/, "")
    controller = controller_name.camelize.constantize.new
    controller.action_methods.each do |action|
      # if you don't want the controller name in your path match, just omit it...
      match "#{controller_route_name}/#{action}" => "#{controller_route_name}##{action}", :as => "#{controller_route_name}_#{action}"
    end
  end
end
```

If you only want to do this for your pages_controller.rb file, then:

```
controller_name = "pages_controller"
controller_route_name = "pages"
controller = controller_name.camelize.constantize.new
controller.action_methods.each do |action|
  # I've removed the controller_route_name from the match here...
  match "#{action}" => "#{controller_route_name}##{action}", :as => "#{controller_route_name}_#{action}"
end
```

**Now, if *dynamic* means "generate a route whenever I dynamically generate a new action"**:

You could really play with fire. Any of your existing actions can define new actions and routes. For example, I could define a route in `config/routes.rb` (but this could be *any* existing route):

```
match '/dynamic_define' => 'application#dynamic_define'
```

Couple that with a method in `ApplicationController` (again, this could be any existing action):

```
def dynamic_define
  method_name = params[:mname]
  self.class.send(:define_method, method_name) {
    render :text => "output from #{method_name}"
  }
  Rails.application.routes.disable_clear_and_finalize = true
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    match "/#{method_name}" => "application##{method_name}", :as => "application_#{method_name}"
  end
  render :text => "dynamic_define just created a new action named #{method_name}"
end
```

In your browser, you can visit:

```
/dynamic_define?mname=my_new_dynamic_action
# browser renders "dynamic_define just created a new action named my_new_dynamic_action"
```

And then visit:

```
/my_new_dynamic_action
# browser renders "output from my_new_dynamic_action"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get as far as:

```
link_to 'Click me', pages_path(:action)
```

by redirecting

```
match ':action' => 'pages#:action'
match '/pages/:action' => redirect(":action") # pages_path(:action) will match
```

This is less typing than the approach suggested in the first answer, but seems less expressive if anything.

I suppose you could override method_missing in your view class to catch pages_[stuff]_path and generate the proper string, e.g.

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if name =~ /^pages_[a-z]*_path$/
    "/#{name.to_s.gsub!(/^pages_/,'').gsub!(/_path$/,'')}"
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Forgive me if my method_missing knowledge or regex capabilities are lacking - hopefully this is helpful directionally at least.

Comment: This is definitely on track. So unless someone suggests a better way to do this, I'll select this as the correct answer in a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For what it's worth I tested this this morning and it works (once you cast `name` to a string, and assuming you don't have any non-alpha characters (like "_") in your action, but the latter is just a regex tweak). The only question left for me is where to put it. For testing purposes I just put it at the top of the view, but that is clunky. If you decide to do this and figure out a good spot, I'd be curious to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your route like that, the right way to access it is:

```
link_to 'Click me', action_path(:action => 'foobar')
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I'm looking to have the paths named dynamically, though, so I can access them with 'foobar_path' instead of specifying the action explicitly. I know I can do that with the ':as' options for individual paths. Any way to do that dynamically? Thanks!

Comment: why would you want paths to load dynamically? do you know that they are helpers based on your router configuration, right? I don't think the rails router is dynamic...